An element $x$ has finitely many conjugates if and only if $\langle x\rangle$ has finite index in its normal closure

An element $x$ has finitely many conjugates if and only if $\langle x\rangle$ has finite index in its normal closure

How to prove that statement? I know that $x$ has finitely many conjugates equals to $|G : C_G(x)|$ being finite or that $\langle x \rangle$ has finitely many conjugates or that $|G : N_G(\langle x \rangle)|$ is finite. But why are all these conditions equivalent to
$\langle x \rangle$ having finite index in its normal closure?

Please use Mathjax.

Doesn't the group $G= (\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}) \rtimes C_2$ have a counterexample, where $C_2 = \langle \sigma\rangle$ is the group of order $2$ which acts on $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ by permuting its factors? You can take $x = (1, 0) \rtimes e$; its conjugates are equal to $(1, 0) \rtimes e$ and $(0, 1) \rtimes e$. However, the normal closure is equal to the group generated by these two elements, which is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, and the group $\langle x \rangle = \mathbb{Z}$ has infinite index in the normal closure.

In this article it says that  is almost normal if and only if it is nearly normal, the second page just above lemma 2.1. So is it a mistake?https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265948379_Infinite_groups_with_many_generalized_normal_subgroups
